# How to connect two players over turn based api game center?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, multiplayer

I am trying to make a turn based game with turn based game center api but I have this problem. I have two iPhones, and when I try to connect over game center view, every time it creates new match for iphone 1 and new match for iphone 2. But when I try the real game api then match connect those two iphones as it should. On turn based version, when starting, it says "Starting game..." but in the real game it says "finding players..." first.

How to solve that?

I'm learning and trying from example (spinningyarn - turn based game center) which was in iOS 5 turorials which I bought on ray wenderlich site.